WKWebView not holding navigationDelegate
I have recently started learning iOS development and am currently working on an app that uses WKWebView to display a HighCharts chart inside a SwiftUI app. I have created a UIViewRepresentable called ChartWebView, and a WKNavigationDelegate called ChartWebViewDelegate. Here is my code:
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

enum ChartType: String {
    case HOURLY = "hourly-chart"
    case HISTORICAL = "historical-chart"
    case RECOMMENDATION = "recommendation-chart"
    case SURPRISES = "surprises-chart"
}

class ChartWebViewDelegate: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: ChartWebView
    
    init(_ webview: ChartWebView) {
        self.webView = webview
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Webview finished loading")
        let javascriptString = "showChart('Hi')"
        webView.evaluateJavaScript(javascriptString) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("Webview navigation error:", error.localizedDescription)
    }
}


struct ChartWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    let chartType: ChartType
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let delegate = ChartWebViewDelegate(self)
        webView.navigationDelegate = delegate
        print("Navigation Delegate: \(String(describing: webView.navigationDelegate))")
        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        print("Updating...")
        print(webView.navigationDelegate as Any)
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: chartType.rawValue, withExtension: "html") {
            webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
        } else {
            print("File not found")
        }
    }
}



The output shows this:
Navigation Delegate: Optional(<Stock_Search.ChartWebViewDelegate: 0x60000025c800>)
Updating...
nil

From what I understand, the webView in ChartWebView is unable to hold the navigationDelegate and its printing nil for the second time, which leads to the code in webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) not executing.
Any leads regarding this will be much appreciated.
I have tried removing the delegate, but then it does not work because of asynchronous file loading. Essentially, I want to call the showChart('Hi') method when the chart loads. The html is loading, as I can see the test text I put in it, but the method is not being called for some reason, which I believe is because the delegate is not being help persistently.

Make a Coordinator and use that as the delegate

There's no strong reference to the instance of ChartWebViewDelegate. Make it  a property instead of a local variable.

I am lost here. Can you help me out a bit. What changes do I have to do in order to achieve this? This is my first time working with UIViewRepresentable.

@KishanSeksaria The answers to the linked question show you the pattern you need to follow. When looking at those answers, mentally convert UITextField to WKWebView and delegate to navigationDelegate. It's all the same concept.

The key point here is that inside WKWebView navigationDelegate is defined as weak, meaning it won't be held by WKWebView for you. You have to hold it. So move let delegate = ChartWebViewDelegate(self) to the same level where you have let webView = WKWebView(). You will have to change its initialization too, since you can't just pass self in that case

Thank you everyone for the suggestions. Moving the let delegate = ChartWebViewDelegate() line outside the makeUIView method worked, with minor changes to the Delegate Class.
